# How can I load a page within a div without the page being overlapped by the header and footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm customizing wordpress. In my main document, I have the code for the header and footer and then a div in between to display content. I want to be able to display content from nav links clicked within the main content div. If there's a better solution, please let me know. The issue I'm running into is keeping the header and footer from overlapping the content. I think this way is a non standard way of loading pages. How can I load other other pages while keeping the header and footer in place and not overlapping the content.

Comment: How are you doing it now?

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by increasing the z-index value of that particular . Increasing the z-index value of that particular  will make ,header,footer visible at the same time or make the  overlap the header and footer(by increasing z-index value even more).